# Fast pandas filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a pandas dataframe, if the name column entry has an item in a given list.

Here we have a DataFrame

```
x = DataFrame(
    [['sam', 328], ['ruby', 3213], ['jon', 121]], 
    columns=['name', 'score'])
```

Now lets say we have a list, `['sam', 'ruby']` and we want to find all rows where the name is in the list, then sum the score.

The solution I have is as follows:

```
total = 0
names = ['sam', 'ruby']
for name in names:
     identified = x[x['name'] == name]
     total = total + sum(identified['score'])
```

However when the dataframe gets extremely large, and the list of names gets very large too, everything is very very slow.

Is there any faster alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) (thanks to DSM for suggesting `loc` over `ix` here):

```
In [78]: x = pd.DataFrame([['sam',328],['ruby',3213],['jon',121]], columns = ['name', 'score'])

In [79]: names = ['sam', 'ruby']

In [80]: x['name'].isin(names)
Out[80]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: name, dtype: bool

In [81]: x.loc[x['name'].isin(names), 'score'].sum()
Out[81]: 3541
```

---

CT Zhu suggests a faster alternative using `np.in1d`:

```
In [105]: y = pd.concat([x]*1000)
In [109]: %timeit y.loc[y['name'].isin(names), 'score'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 413 µs per loop

In [110]: %timeit y.loc[np.in1d(y['name'], names), 'score'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 335 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but am just testing now, how quickly it speeds up! Will let you know

Comment: Just checked. Speeded up phenomenally! Thanks again

Comment: Very elegant, I was about to suggest `x[np.in1d(x['name'], ['sam', 'ruby'])].sum()` but it is actually twice slower.

Comment: @CTZhu: Try `x.ix[np.in1d(x['name'], names), 'score'].sum()`. It is faster than using `isin` on my machine. I think the difference is because `x[np.in1d(x['name'], ['sam', 'ruby'])]` includes the `name` column, and summing over the names probably triggers an exception. Handling the exception is what is slow.

Comment: Do you get a difference with `.loc` instead of `.ix`?  For me that reduces the `isin` time down to the `in1d` time.  [Although it makes the `in1d` time faster too..]

Comment: ``loc`` will be faster than ``ix`` as it doesn't have to check whether things 'look' like integers but are actually locations; ``in1d`` is not well suited to ``datetime64[ns]`` or ``timedelta64[ns]`` types FYI

Comment: @DSM: Thanks for the suggestion. I've replaced `ix` with `loc`, above.

Comment: @Jeff: Are you referring to [this](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-October/058927.html)? I'm having trouble reproducing that problem. Do you have an example?

Comment: @unutbu no, I was refering that numpy < 1.7, ``np.in1d`` was broken (and that's why ``isin`` exists). In does work though. Also isin is somewhat faster (and I think used to be much faster prior to 1.7.1 or .2 IIRC when ``in1d`` was fixed)

Comment: just to share I have a super large two column dataset and here are the results:
> using (isin+loc)....... time = 31.4 seconds / df iteration
> not using................... time = 95.9 seconds / df iteration

Answer (score 13):

If I need to search on a field, I have noticed that it helps immensely if I **change the index** of the DataFrame to the search field. For one of my search and lookup requirements I got a performance improvement of around **500%**.

So in your case the following could be used to search and filter by name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['sam', 328], ['ruby', 3213], ['jon', 121]], 
                 columns=['name', 'score'])
names = ['sam', 'ruby']

df_searchable = df.set_index('name')

df_searchable[df_searchable.index.isin(names)]
```

**Update Dec-21**

Updates are driven by the comments on this answer.

Looking at the details of my use case, its not magic that is happening here. My use case was that of running millions of look-ups on a column with around 45k values. From what I remember, it was a lookup on US zip-codes. Understandably, once the set_index has incurred it's one time optimization cost, subsequent look-ups become way faster. The overall effect is magnified because of the large number of look-ups, the cost of optimization getting amortized over all the numerous look-ups.

The impressive performance improvement number is essentially due to the highly amortized optimization cost.

Comment: This comment is essential. I have a dataframe with 10 million rows, and searching on index speeded it up tremendously.

Comment: Do you have an example for this performance boost? I tried it in pandas 1.2.2 with 15 million rows and it was not faster than `df1[df1.names.isin(df2.names)]`, especially not with the additional `.set_index()` and `.reset_index()` steps required to return the same result.

Comment: @00schneider - I had a use case where I was generating millions of rows for a schema. Some of these columns were dependent on other columns and were generated by a lookup. The lookup itself was on a data set of around 45k rows. After the set_index operation, which was a one time thing for my use case, the numerous lookups became way faster.

For a single lookup, the set_index cost may not be justified for the lookup speed up.

Comment: Is this also true when the column you are making index has duplicates?

Comment: @skdhfgeq2134 - The performance improvement is essentially due to the set_index cost amortization. I don't think duplicates in the lookup column should make much of a difference to the benefit due to amortization. Although the semantics of a lookup on a column with duplicates is slightly different. We will mostly need some second level lookup within the first level lookup result set. Overall performance will depend on the average cardinality of this result set.

Answer (score 11):

If your data repeats a lot of values, try using the 'categorical' data type for that column and then applying boolean filtering. Much more flexible than using indices and, at least in my case, much faster.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype={'name':'category'})
data[(data.name=='sam')&(data.score>1)]
```

or

```
names=['sam','ruby']    
data[data.name.isin(names)]
```

For the ~15 million row, ~200k unique terms dataset I'm working with in pandas 1.2, *%timeit* results are:

- boolean filter on object column: **608ms**
- .loc filter on same object column as index: **281ms**
- boolean filter on same object column as 'categorical' type: **16ms**

From there, add the .sum() or whatever aggregation function you're looking for.

Comment: Converting repeated string values to categorical(in fact, the string column is really  a category), reduced process of 33 mins to 1.30 minutes! Thanks, simple but efficient.

Comment: Wow, got an improvement in filtering of 10x!