# loc in dataframe filtering taking lots of time

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe Emp (Details of employess) having 3,500,000 rows and 5 columns. I have to filter Dataframe based on Emp_Name=="John". I am using loc for this purpose. But this step is taking several hours. What is the best and fastest way to filter dataframe with huge dataset?

```
Emp_subset=Emp.loc[Emp['Emp_Name'] == "John"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738882/fast-pandas-filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be taking that long. There's no need to use loc here.

Try this and see how much it speeds things up:

`emp_subset=Emp[Emp['Emp_Name'] == "John"]`

Also try not to use capitals for df object names as it could lead to confusion: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/